# Moments of inertia of benzene and ammonia as symmetrial tops

Tags: physical-chemistry

Hello I was reading about symmetrical tops and how their properties relate to their rotational spectra. According to the 8th edition of *Atkins*, those molecules have one unique principal axis which includes a moment of inertia (denoted $I_{∥}$). They also have two orthogonal moments of inertia, which are equal in magnitude (denoted  $I_{⊥}$).

Unfortunately, the book doesn't give any pictural representation, so my question remains: Do all moments of inertia need to be orthogonal to one another or just to the principal axis? On the internet I find conflicting information for the moments of inertia for benzene, as seen here.

[image]

Here, you can see that the two $I_{⊥}$ (a,b) are not orthogonal to each other, but in this illustration they are (A, B):

[image]

So, which is it? And would this representation of ammonia be correct for the three moments of inertia?

[image]

Comment: The three I axes are always orthogonal and along x, y, z, but the I values along these directions can differ depending on geometry. You can choose any set of xyz orientation wrt to the molecule but its easier to use the molecules symmetry axes if possible. The molecule rotates about the total angular momentum which is the vector sum the 3 components. See chapter 7 of https://applying-maths-book.com/ for a discussion and examples of the 3x3 matrix you may need to diagonalise in the general case if you choose arbitrary xyz. Diagonalising rotates the axes to be along molecules own MOI direction.

Comment: There is non fundamental need for the axes to be orthogonal, merely non-coplanar is enough for a complete description of the object. This is so the unit vectors in the directions of the axes form a complete basis for the three dimensional space. But certainly if you can choose your axes an orthogonal choice will almost always make your life easier.

Comment: So @IanBush both options I mentioned for the two inertia axis (a,b) for benzene that I mentioned can be considered correct?

Comment: All the above are valid choices. They just may not have the same values. See @porphyrin comment on diagonalisation about relating them.

Comment: @IanBush But we can only measure two rotational constants for the molecule can’t we?  So there should be only two or am I wrong? And about porphyrins comment, I am not that deep into the topic as my expertise is in bioorganic chemistry so its a bit difficult to understand 

Comment: We can measure one transition energy when exciting an electron from the 1s state in Hydrogen to the set of 2p orbitals. So are you claiming there is only a single 2p state, and not 3, namely 2px, 2py and 2pz? Just because we measure 1 number doesn't mean it corresponds to just 1 thing. This is what degeneracy is. At least in quantum land.

Comment: Yeah that is true, I see what you mean. The thing I was not sure about, is that the moments of inertia would correspond to the same energies, for example in the benzene example, it was not obvious to me that I(a) in the first example would have the same energy as I(b) in the second..